# How to wrap in rows with display flex and delete white spaces if a box is higher than others

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a structure like this with flex:
[image]

But I can't get it working because the Items aligned on a row are occupying a space. Is there any way to achieve this?

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.container div.section {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

div.section:nth-child(2) {
  height: 400px;
}

div.section:nth-child(3) {
  height: 280px;
}

div.section:nth-child(4) {
  height: 280px;
}

div.section:nth-child(6) {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section menu_0"></div>
  <div class="section menu_1"></div>
  <div class="section menu_2"></div>
  <div class="section menu_3"></div>
  <div class="section menu_4"></div>
  <div class="section menu_5"></div>
  <div class="section menu_6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you cant use flexbox for this. CSS grid would work.

Comment: @Moose, I've never used grid property (heard of it). Could you provide a similar example with that structure?

Comment: I've a little [cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for you, maybe you can figure it out.

Comment: The links other commenters have provided give great information and instructions for CSS grid =)

Answer (score 3):

I think this will helps you (Find Full Code Here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pinBoot').pinterest_grid({
no_columns: 4,
padding_x: 10,
padding_y: 10,
margin_bottom: 50,
single_column_breakpoint: 700
});
});
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = 'pinterest_grid',
        defaults = {
            padding_x: 10,
            padding_y: 10,
            no_columns: 3,
            margin_bottom: 50,
            single_column_breakpoint: 700
        },
        columns,
        $article,
        article_width;

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
        var self = this,
            resize_finish;

        $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(resize_finish);
            resize_finish = setTimeout( function () {
                self.make_layout_change(self);
            }, 11);
        });

        self.make_layout_change(self);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(window).resize();
        }, 500);
    };

    Plugin.prototype.calculate = function (single_column_mode) {
        var self = this,
            tallest = 0,
            row = 0,
            $container = $(this.element),
            container_width = $container.width();
            $article = $(this.element).children();

        if(single_column_mode === true) {
            article_width = $container.width() - self.options.padding_x;
        } else {
            article_width = ($container.width() - self.options.padding_x * self.options.no_columns) / self.options.no_columns;
        }

        $article.each(function() {
            $(this).css('width', article_width);
        });

        columns = self.options.no_columns;

        $article.each(function(index) {
            var current_column,
                left_out = 0,
                top = 0,
                $this = $(this),
                prevAll = $this.prevAll(),
                tallest = 0;

            if(single_column_mode === false) {
                current_column = (index % columns);
            } else {
                current_column = 0;
            }

            for(var t = 0; t < columns; t++) {
                $this.removeClass('c'+t);
            }

            if(index % columns === 0) {
                row++;
            }

            $this.addClass('c' + current_column);
            $this.addClass('r' + row);

            prevAll.each(function(index) {
                if($(this).hasClass('c' + current_column)) {
                    top += $(this).outerHeight() + self.options.padding_y;
                }
            });

            if(single_column_mode === true) {
                left_out = 0;
            } else {
                left_out = (index % columns) * (article_width + self.options.padding_x);
            }

            $this.css({
                'left': left_out,
                'top' : top
            });
        });

        this.tallest($container);
        $(window).resize();
    };

    Plugin.prototype.tallest = function (_container) {
        var column_heights = [],
            largest = 0;

        for(var z = 0; z < columns; z++) {
            var temp_height = 0;
            _container.find('.c'+z).each(function() {
                temp_height += $(this).outerHeight();
            });
            column_heights[z] = temp_height;
        }

        largest = Math.max.apply(Math, column_heights);
        _container.css('height', largest + (this.options.padding_y + this.options.margin_bottom));
    };

    Plugin.prototype.make_layout_change = function (_self) {
        if($(window).width() < _self.options.single_column_breakpoint) {
            _self.calculate(true);
        } else {
            _self.calculate(false);
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
body {
 background-color:#eee;   
}    

#pinBoot {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.white-panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
/*
stylize any heading tags withing white-panel below
*/

.white-panel h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.white-panel h1 a {
  color: #A92733;
}
.white-panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Pinterest Responsive Grid</h2>

    <p>Best viewed <a href="http://bootsnipp.com/iframe/Zkk0O" target="_blank">full screen</a>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <section id="pinBoot">

      <article class="white-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sDLIAZD.png" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 1</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8lhFhc1.gif" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 2</a></h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xOIMvAe.jpg" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 3</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      </article>


      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3gXW3L3.jpg" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 4</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o2RVMqm.jpg" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 5</a></h4>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kFFpuKA.jpg" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 6</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      </article>



      <article class="white-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/E9RmLPA.jpg" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 7</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

      <article class="white-panel"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8lhFhc1.gif" alt="">
        <h4><a href="#">Title 8</a></h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>

    </section>


    <hr>


  </div>
  <p>
    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbootsnipp.com%2Fiframe%2FZkk0O" target="_blank"><small>HTML</small><sup>5</sup></a>
    <br>
    <br>

  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: This snippet is really useful but I'm not using bootstrap.